# Prove $\mathbb{V}(Y) = \mathbb{E}\mathbb{V}(Y \mid X) + \mathbb{V}\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Trying to figure out how to prove this statement
$\mathbb{V}(Y) = \mathbb{EV}(Y\mid X) + \mathbb{VE}(Y\mid X)$

Tried expanding RHS as follows:

\begin{align}&= \mathbb{EV}(Y\mid X)+\mathbb{VE}(Y\mid X)\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\int [y-\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)]^2f(y\mid x)\,dy] + \int[\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)-\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)]^2 f(x)\,dx \\
&= \int\int (y-\mathbb{E}(Y|X)^2f(y|x)dyf(x)\,dx + \int[\mathbb{E}(Y|X)-\mathbb{E}(Y)]^2 f(x)\,dx\;\text{ since }\;\mathbb{EE}(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}(Y)\\
&= \int\int[y^2 -2y\mathbb{E}(Y|X) + \mathbb{E}(Y|X)^2]f(x,y)\,dy\,dx + \int[\mathbb{E}(Y|X)^2 -2\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Y|X)+\mathbb{E}(Y)^2]f(x)\,dx\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: This is the **law of total variance**. A proof can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance#Proof.

Answer (score 2):

As @Minus One-Twelfth mentioned, this is the *law of total variance*.

***Proof***
\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}[Y] &= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2\\
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y^2 \mid X]\Big] - \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\Big]^2\\
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{V}[Y \mid X] + \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]^2\Big] - \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\Big]^2\\
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{V}[Y \mid X]\Big] + \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]^2\Big] - \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\Big]^2\\
&= \mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{V}[Y \mid X]\Big] + \mathbb{V}\Big[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\Big]\,.
\end{align}

The first step is just the definition of the variance;
the second step is introducing an independent variable $X$,
the third step then applies the definition of variance, but ``the other way around''.
The fourth step uses the linearity of the expected value operator,
and the fifth and final step then reapplies the definition of the variance to group the rightmost terms into a single variance term.